# How to run an existing Scala project using VS Code and Metals?

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, sbt, scala-ide, scala-metals

I am brand new to Scala and I find that [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/) is very slow on my machine for basic things like searching the codebase and editing code. I am used to Visual Studio Code and was very happy to find [this metals extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=scalameta.metals).

I was able to "import build" and fix issues like bumping up scala version in my projects but I am not sure how to reproduce this step to set up a run configuration and actually launch our app in Scala IDE.

[image]
[image]

We have a parent folder which has a bunch of projects and a 'consoleapp' project which is the main entry point of our app - it imports the logic/routes of all other projects.

```
|____parent
| |____consoleapp
| |____project1
| |____project2
```

I tried `sbt run` and `sbt runMain consoleapp` from within the consoleapp folder and also the parent folder but they didn't work.

I am not sure what other information from our setup is relevant - happy to provide more info as needed.

**Updated** to add more details below:

**consoleapp/build.sbt**

```
name := "consoleapp"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

packMain := Map("consoleapp" -> "consoleapp")

libraryDependencies ++=  Seq (...)
```

**Output of commands I ran - `sbt run` and `sbt runMain`**

Running from ~/scala/parent

```
> sbt run                                                                                                                                                                 masterstate [0a8dab85] modified
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from metals.sbt,build.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/pradhyo/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pradhyo/scala/parent/project
[info] Loading settings for project consoleapp from build.sbt ...
... 
Loading settings for all other projects in parent folder
...
[info] Loading settings for project parent from build.sbt ...
[info] Resolving key references (22435 settings) ...
[info] Set current project to parent (in build file:/Users/pradhyo/scala/parent/)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRun for the full output
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 18-Dec-2019 1:41:25 PM
```

Running from ~/scala/parent

```
> sbt "runMain consoleapp.consoleapp"                                                                                                                                     masterstate [0a8dab85] modified
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from metals.sbt,build.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/pradhyo/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pradhyo/scala/parent/project
[info] Loading settings for project consoleapp from build.sbt ...
... 
Loading settings for all other projects in parent folder
...
[info] Loading settings for project parent from build.sbt ...
[info] Resolving key references (22435 settings) ...
[info] Set current project to parent (in build file:/Users/pradhyo/scala/parent/)
[info] running consoleapp.consoleapp 
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: consoleapp.consoleapp
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: consoleapp.consoleapp
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRunMain for the full output
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / runMain) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 18-Dec-2019 1:46:21 PM
```

Running from ~/scala/parent/consoleapp

```
> sbt run                                                                                                                                                                 masterstate [0a8dab85] modified
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from metals.sbt,build.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/pradhyo/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pradhyo/scala/parent/consoleapp/project
[info] Loading settings for project consoleapp from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to consoleapp (in build file:/Users/pradhyo/scala/parent/consoleapp/)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRun for the full output
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 18-Dec-2019 1:49:26 PM
```

Running from ~/scala/parent/consoleapp

```
> sbt "runMain consoleapp"                                                                                                                                                masterstate [0a8dab85] modified
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from metals.sbt,build.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/pradhyo/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pradhyo/scala/parent/consoleapp/project
[info] Loading settings for project consoleapp from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to consoleapp (in build file:/Users/pradhyo/scala/parent/consoleapp/)
[info] running consoleapp 
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: consoleapp
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: consoleapp
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRunMain for the full output
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / runMain) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 18-Dec-2019 1:50:06 PM
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've edited more information into the post

Comment: It seems you do not have any scala files in your project... ?! At least there is no `consoleapp` object found, nor any other file suitable as a main class.

Comment: I would recommend you to create a little git repo with your code and publish it here.

Comment: Yes, that is the exact same problem I encountered. The existing project was a couple of years old (still in development of course) using scala `2.11.7` even. I wouldn't work because of the scala version , which I couldn't bump because it was inheritance system , so I never managed to make it work because of that ,even though I got every recommendation to use Metals I was left quite disappointed by it.

Comment: @amer I was going to recreate the issue with a small git repo over the weekend. How are you sure it is because of the Scala version? Do you know which of the commands I ran is the correct one?

Comment: @cbley I do have Scala files and a consoleapp object.. will try to reproduce the issue in a brand new setup and update with GitHub link over the weekend

Comment: @pradhyo sbt run .. I think I found somewhere on the Metals page supported versions for plugin and 2.11 wasn't one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After following the instructions in the [Scala Metals VSCode Readme](https://github.com/scalameta/metals-vscode/blob/main/packages/metals-vscode/README.md), use a launch configuration similar to this for the Eclipse screenshots in the question.

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "scala",
            "name": "Debug consoleapp",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "consoleapp",
            "buildTarget": "consoleapp",
            "args": [],
            "jvmOptions": ["-J-Dconfig.file=/path/to/config/file"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I had trouble passing the config file for [pureconfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig) correctly. Here's [the Github issue](https://github.com/scalameta/metals-vscode/issues/304) with the correct `jvmOptions` line.

Answer (score 0):

> Metals supports these Scala versions 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.12.8, 2.12.9,
>   2.12.10, 2.12.7 and 2.11.12

This is something I noticed from their documentation([doc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=scalameta.metals)). So it could pinpoint to your and mine problem which I addressed in comments.

Your `scalaVersion := "2.12.3"` is not listed here.

Comment: I updated my post now - I had bumped up my scala version to 2.12.10 but still got the same error. I undid the changes as they didn't work and posted later so copied the original code and forgot to make the change to the scalaVersion line. But I am not sure if the scala version is causing the issues with the sbt commands - if my understanding is correct, I need to find the external command to run my project and configure VS Code to use it and this step has nothing to do with metals.